# 2D Interpolation using nth

Tags: scala, math, interpolation, polynomial-approximations

Let's say I have 2 arrays

```
 x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 y = [4,53,234,43,12,2]
```

Polynomial of degree `n` to fit `y = F(x)`. How to interpolate y from x

Comment: Have a look at Apache Commons Math.

Answer (score 2):

One can use [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/). Here's an example

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val x = 1 to 6
val y = Array(4, 53, 234, 43, 12, 2)
val n = 5

val fitter = PolynomialCurveFitter.create(n)
val result = fitter.fit((x zip y).map { case (a, b) =>
  new WeightedObservedPoint(1, a, b)
}.asJava)

println(result.toList)
```